# Rails CSV Import Causing Numbers with Leading 0 to Mess Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I've wrote the code to import addresses via an uploaded CSV file that sometimes includes postal codes that have a leading 0.

The problem is that the postal codes that have a leading 0 are not imported properly. For example, an address that was imported with a postal code of `02420` ultimately is saved to the db at `1296`. Not sure what's going on. Not sure if there's a pattern that was used to convert the `02420` to `1296`

Every other postal code and aspect of all addresses are import correctly.

**Here's the app setup:**

- Rails 4
- Postgresql
- Ruby CSV
- Postal Code column in db is a string [character varying(255)]

**What I've tried:**

- Double checked the CSV file in a text editor for data integrity
- Created the CSV file with quotes around each field

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something's interpreting that number as an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), as it starts with "0".

Comment: You'll probably have to show us the code that processes the file.

Comment: You can view the source code that pertains to the issue here: https://gist.github.com/khedaywi/ccf74dd55d0ad0a881d4

The CSV file being uploaded is in the gist as well. I've tried putting quotes around each field in the csv but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. Somewhere along the way it had to be converting the 02420 (or any other number with a leading 0) to an octal number (thanks [Melvin Kicchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104717/melvin-kicchi))

The original code:

`CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true, converters: :all, encoding: 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|`

The code that fixed the conversion:

`CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true, encoding: 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|`

Needed to remove the `converters: :all`, since the parser was converting all different types of data and therefore passing the 02420 as an integer, which later became an octal number.

Thanks for the help! Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

You can read more about [Ruby's CSV Converters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 student.addresses.create(
      line1: row["address_line1"],
      line2: row["address_line2"],
      line3: row["address_line3"],
      city: row["address_city"],
      state: row["address_state"],
      postal: row["address_postal"].try(:to_s),
      country: row["address_country"],
      kind: row["address_address_kind"]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

The issue ended up being that I was using all of Ruby's CSV converters when creating the hash, which likely ended up making everything with a leading 0 turn into an octal.